# Scroll position restoration for child root

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem to get back to a particular scroll position.
There is a list of lazy-loaded objects in my ObjectListComponent, once I click on the Object name I can check its details. There is a return button, which leads to a previous page with the list of Objects. The problem is that ObjectListComponent is being init from the start and I cannot get back to a previous state, the one before I checked a particular object's details. I need to have my scrollable list of objects and, if I enter ObjectComponent in order to check its details and want to go back to the list, I land on the ObjectList in the very same place my single object is, so I could scroll down and get more objects loaded.

There is an option like 
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled' } // <-- HERE
)

But I have RouterModule.forChild and it doesn't accept extra options as an argument.

Comment: Idk if this would help, in my case it was also for child root - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214772/angular-8-restore-scroll-position-when-browser-back-button-is-selected-in-child

Answer (score 1):

I had a chance to work on same requirement and there is no default configuration which would support scroll restoration in any front end frameworks. I have gone through many references with very complex code. I thought to develop by my own and implemented in following way:

1. First get the scroll position using `document.documentElement.scrollTop` and map to `this.router.url` (previous url) in object.
2. After returning to same page, compare with `url` in above object and apply corresponding position for that page.
3. **SPA Problem:** Async loading of different pages takes different times to render hence apply scroll position effects. To solve this issue, we can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to properly apply scroll position.
4. In your home component, subscribe to router events and start implementing

here:

```
scrollPos = {};
attempts = 5;
interval: any;
maxAttempts = 5;
scrollRestore() {
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
this.scrollPos[this.router.url] = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
this.scrollPos[event.url] ? 
this.applyScroll(this.scrollPos[event.url]):this.applyScroll(0)
}
});
}

applyScroll(pos) {
 this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, position);
  this.attempts++;
  this.clearScrollInterval(pos);
}, 30);
}

clearScrollInterval(pos) {
if (this.interval &&
  (this.attempts === this.maxAttempts || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= pos)) {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
  this.attempts= 0;
}
}
```